# Langlands reciprocity for C*-algebras

Tags: nt.number-theory, oa.operator-algebras, langlands-conjectures

I just came across [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.03054v1) which, judging by what I understood, establishes the Langlands reciprocity conjecture for a certain Shimura variety. My question, regardless of the validity of the proof, is: would such a result have far-reaching consequences in number theory? If so, what would they be?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From reding the first page of the paper I can say that it is rubbish. The author speaks of Shimura varieties attached to reductive groups, but not all groups have such, he introduces convolution on $L^2(\Gamma\backslash G)$ which is not well-defined and so on.

Comment: @Corbennick The author has a record of taking genuine stuff from Cstar algebras (irrational tori, etc) and then coming up with grander and grander window-dressing. (I'm not qualified to judge the correctness or otherwise of said window-dressing.)

Comment: It seems to me that the indicated preprint gets so far off the rails so quickly that it's hard to visualize specific details of a plausible, corrected version. E.g., the "convolution" product at the bottom of the first page certainly does not converge, ... but there are many related integrals which _do_, but, ... And, yes, as @Corbennick comments, not all reductive groups have arithmetic quotients which are algebraic varieties... So the notion of a "corrected" version is too ambiguous to discuss, I fear.